# git push to create new GitHub repo not working

Tags: bash, git, github

I am trying to create a script that prompts for a name to give to a new GitHub repo, and then create the GitHub repo by pushing to the remote URL which the new GitHub repo will have. When I use the script I get these errors:

> remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/JT-style/great.git/' not found

```
read -p"Enter the name of remote repository: " name
mkdir ~/rep/$name
cd ~/rep/$name
echo "#$name" >> README.md
git init 
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/JT-style/$name.git
git push -u origin main

echo "Done"
```

Why doesn't this work? What can I do to achieve my goal?

p.s. This is my first script.

Comment: Put a valid shebang and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: You can't push to a repo if it doesn't already exist on github. You should try to use [gh](https://cli.github.com/) if you want to create remote repository from command line.

Comment: @BlackBeans you better post that as an answer because that's what it is. :-)

Comment: The error is reported by Git on `git push`. It is not an error in the script. Using shellcheck.net is a good advice in general but it probably does not help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't push to a repository to github if it doesn't already exist. Usually, you'd create one through a web browser by going on their site, but they released a cli called [gh](https://cli.github.com), which allows creating repositories (you have to authenticate somehow before though).

Comment: @axiac thank you so much sir. Your answer came to me and i  realized that error is not in the script. Then i read the BlackBeans answer and saw the whole picture.

Comment: I couldn’t have done it without you.You advice got me to thinking how i can use my script in a right way. The first thing i do is create a new repo on github then i run my script. You helped me see that.